# How can I modify a virtual disk (.vmdk) on a remote host (ESXI 5), while the virtual machine is off?

Tags: windows, mount, remote, esxi, vmdk

I urgently need help with this one.
I have a server (ESXI 5) running a Windows Server VM. The preallocated virtual disk drive storing the OS ran out of space and the VM is failing to start due to this.

I need to mount and modify this .vmdk file as fast as possible to clear up enough space to get it running again.

TLDR;
How to mount a remote VMDK file on and ESXI 5 host to a Windows 10 PC (with read/write permissions) OR a more efficient way of fixing the above issue.

Comment: I'd attach it to another VM as a secondary drive (d:\ ?) and clear up your space. Alternately, lots of tutorials indicate that you can use the VMWare DiskMount utility to mount the vmdk on windows (though the interior filesystm may also be a problem if the VM isn't windows). http://www.vladan.fr/mounting-your-vmdk-disks-directly-to-your-windows-box-how-to/

Comment: Excellent, thank you for a quick response @Frank Thomas. I will try this now and keep you posted.

Comment: If you have free space in your datastore then increase the HDD size of that VM.